# Extract text from webpage with ChromeDriverManager (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, driver

I need to get the core question asked on this page and so far this is the code I have used. The problem is that it brings me 'to next question' instead of the expected core question.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,850")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = 'http://ipaulgraham.herokuapp.com/'      
driver.get(url)

for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'question')]"):
    print(i.text)

--to next question
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the question is inside a div that has `question` as its id. I guess you can do something like:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
element = browser.find_element(By.ID, "question")
print(element.text)
```